# Parsing JSON with SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I'm having trouble parsing the following JSON file with SwiftyJSON. I've looked around the web and tried different suggested solutions with no luck.

Here is the JSON:

```
{'info-leag':{'Status':1,'Name':'Testing Name','url-lig':'test.testing.com','uid':'12345'}}
```

And my relevant code:

```
//initializes request
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()) { response, maybeData, error in
        if let data = maybeData {

            let json = JSON(data: data)


            //stores data as UTF8 String
            let contents = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

The first part seems to work fine, I am able to get the JSON and save it as data, at the bottom I converted it to a string to make sure that I was getting the right information, I then later print it to make sure.

I tried different things like:

```
let name = json["info-league"]["Name"] //can't seem to get the context
```

I'm trying to get the Name and uid to be saved as 2 strings as well as the Status as an int.

Thanks!

Comment: If this is the actual JSON response, it's invalid: single quotes should be double quotes. Also, there's a typo in your example: "info-league" ≠ "info-leag"

Comment: You can use www.jsonlint.com to validate your JSON

Comment: This is the actual JSON response, I'll work on changing it.  Once I have it in a double quote format, would the syntax I used above work? (assuming no typo)

Comment: Yes, it will work with your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've made your JSON valid like this:

> {"info-league":{"Status":1,"Name":"Testing Name","url-lig":"test.testing.com","uid":"12345"}}

you will be able to use your example, it works (I just tested):

```
let name = json["info-league"]["Name"]
```

but it's better to use SwiftyJSON types:

```
let name = json["info-league"]["Name"].string
let status = json["info-league"]["Status"].int
```

so your variables are of known types for later use.

If you don't do this they will be of type `JSON`, a type created by SwiftyJSON, and you will have to cast them later (not a problem, depends how you're organised in your code).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let name = json["info-league"]["Name"].string
```